# Data JPA. Query by Example. Can't search using Long value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, query-by-example

I have got an entity Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
    private String model;
    //setters and getters
}
```

Here how I'm trying to query by example:

```
ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity();
product.setId(productId);
Example<ProductEntity> ex = Example.of(product);
Page<ProductEntity> pages = productRepository.findAll(ex, page);
```

But I get PostgreSQL error:
PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "L".

Here's query that was created:

```
Hibernate: select productent0_.id as id1_13_, productent0_.brand_id as brand_id9_13_, productent0_.imgPath as imgPath2_13_, productent0_.model as model3_13_, productent0_.numberOfEvaluation as numberOf4_13_, productent0_.priceBuy as priceBuy5_13_, productent0_.priceSell as priceSel6_13_, productent0_.rating as rating7_13_, productent0_.sumOfEvaluation as sumOfEva8_13_, productent0_.type_id as type_id10_13_ from Products productent0_ where (productent0_.id=1L ) limit ?
```

The systax error is here:

```
where (productent0_.id=1L )
```

It adds 'L' character for Long value. So, how can I solve this problem?

UPDATE:
Any idies? Still can't solve this problem.

UPDATE: My repository:

```
public interface CrudProductRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductEntity, Long>{
}
```

The package of JpaRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
```

Comment: What is the package of Example ? (good chance lucking looking Example and Hibernate on search engine :( ) And I'd say the error is here the fact that 1L should have been a parameter rather than being hard wired into the query.

Comment: ya , for me , work was  `where (productent0_.id=1% )`. criteriabuilder may give you this functionality.

Comment: import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
Is this right one?

Comment: which versions of hibernate and spring-data are you running?

Comment: @NoDataFound, any ideas, please?

Comment: @lucsbelt, I use Hibernate 4.3.1, Spring Data Jpa 1.11.10, Spring Data Commons 1.13.10 and Spring 4.3.14. Are these OK?

Comment: Can you post your repository code?

Comment: @lucsbelt, I updated my post. You can see my repository there. Will be be grateful for your help!

Comment: y suggest update hibernate to 5+ and test it again